# Django field DateField with year only or with year and month etc. with filtering

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, django-models

I have a question regarding the DateField.  Is there any possibility for the field to accept only a year or a year and a month?  I want to add an incomplete date to the database and filter by this field.  I download books from API and the date is not always full there.  I want to download the results, save them to the database and display a list of these objects on the page with an incomplete date or a complete date.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to complete the date received from API and you will have more control over that. You can filter by **year** and **month**.

You can have a function to check and complete the date received from API and store it.

```
Books.objects.filter(date__year=today.year, date__month=today.month).
```